# Using Perl to remove n characters from the end of multiple lines

Tags: string, perl

I want to remove n characters from each line using PERL.

For example, I have the following input:

catbathatxx   (length 11; 11%3=2 characters) (Remove 2 characters from this line)

mansunsonx    (length 10; 10%3=1 character)  (Remove 1 character from this line)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open FH, "input.txt";
@array=<FH>;
foreach $tmp(@array)
{
$b=length($tmp)%3;
my $c=substr($tmp, 0, length($tmp)-$b);
print "$c\n";
}
```

I want to output the final string (after the characters have been removed).

However, this program is not giving the correct result. Can you please guide me on what the mistake is?

Thanks a lot. Please let me know if there are any doubts/clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming trailing whitespace is not significant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use constant MULTIPLE_OF => 3;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/\s+\z//;
    next unless my $length = length $line;
    my $chars_to_remove = $length % MULTIPLE_OF;
    $line =~ s/.{$chars_to_remove}\z//;
    print $line, "\n";
}

__DATA__
catbathatxx
mansunsonx
0123456789
012345678
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\K` regex sequence makes this a lot clearer; it was introduced in Perl v5.10.0.

The code looks like this

```
use 5.10.0;
use warnings;

for (qw/ catbathatxx mansunsonx /) {
  (my $s = $_) =~ s/^ (?:...)* \K .* //x;
  say $s;
}
```

**output**

```
catbathat
mansunson
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you would want to post the result you *are* getting. That being said...

Each line in the file has a `\n` (or `\r\n` on windows) on the end of it that you're not accounting for. You need to `chomp()` the line.

**Edit to add:** My perl is getting rusty from non-use but if memory serves me correct you can actually `chomp()` the entire array after reading the file: `chomp(@array)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use chomp() on your array, like this:

```
@array=<FH>;
chomp(@array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -plwe 'chomp; $c = length($_) % 3; chop while $c--' < /tmp/zock.txt
```

Look up the options in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). Note that line endings are characters, too. Get them out of the way using `chomp`; re-add them on output using the `-l` option. Use [`chop`](http://p3rl.org/chop) to efficiently remove characters from the end of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code, you are trying to print just the first 'nx3' characters for the largest value of n for each line.

The following code does this using a simple regular expression.

For each line, it first removes the line ending, then greedy matches
as many `.{3}` as it can (`.` matches any character, `{3}` asks for exactly 3 of them).

The memory requirement of this approach (compared with using an array the size of your file) is fixed.  Not too important if your file is small compared with your free memory, but sometimes files are gigabytes, and sometimes memory is very small.

It's always worth using variable names that reflect the purpose of the variable, rather than things like `$a` or `@array`.  In this case I used only one variable, which I called `$line`.

It's also good practice to close files as soon as you have finished with them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; # This will apply warnings even if you use command perl to run it

open FH, '<', 'input.txt'; # Use three part file open - single quote where no interpolation required.
for my $line (<FH>){
    chomp($line);  
    $line =~ s/((.{3})*).*/$1\n/;
    print $line;
}
close FH;
```